# IOS 5: How to return YES on contains: with 2 'identical' objects, but with different pointers

Tags: web-services, ios5, hash, nsmutablearray, equality

I'm quite new to StackOverflow, so apologies in advance if I forgot some
critical element in my question. It's a long one, so bear with me!

**Iterating over JSON-webservice result:**

For an IOS5 iPad app, I collect JSON information from a webservice and via:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *json = 
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions      
error:&error];
```

I'll iterate over the returned `NSDictionary` and store the returned objects and their properties as a custom class.

The custom class contains several properties, including an `AmountInShoppingCart`-value.

I use this custom class to represent items that we sell in our store, so an `NSMutableArray` is made of all the returned objects and shown to the user.
If the `AmountInShoppingCart value > 0`, then the object will be put in the `ShoppingCart` `NSMutableArray` (which is a singleton).

**Checking for duplicates in ShoppingCart:**

To make sure the `ShoppingCart` doesn't contain any duplicate entries, I've got a function like this in the `ShoppingCartController` (also borrowed from SO):

```
- (void)checkForDuplicates
{
    NSMutableSet *seen = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    NSLog(@"ShoppingCartArray count: %u",[ShoppingCartArray count]);
    //Iterate over the Array to check for duplicates, and to sync the list with the   
    cart.
    while (i < [ShoppingCartArray count]) {
        id obj = [ShoppingCartArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([seen containsObject:obj]) {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyCust class]]){
                MyCust *cust = [ShoppingCartArray objectAtIndex:i];
                MyCust *seenCust = [seen member:obj];
                seenCust.AmountInShoppingCart = cust.AmountInShoppingCart;
                [ShoppingCartArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            }} else {seen addObject:obj];
            i++;}}}
```

**Equality & Hashing**

To accomplish this, I've overridden the `isEqual:`-function of the `MyCust`-class so that it'll look at the `externalItemID`-property, which is the only property that is definitely unique for each class object.

I picked this function up from StackOverflow:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherObject;
{
    if ([otherObject isKindOfClass:[MyCust class]]) {
        MyCust *otherCust= (MyCust *)otherObject;
        if (externalItemId != [otherCust externalItemId]) return NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger) hash;
{
    return [[self externalItemId] hash];
}
```

**Sync the two arrays:**

It can happen that people request the same result from the JSON-webservice, since it uses the MyCust's size, height and diameter to return a set of objects that adhere to those sizes.

So I use the following function to check and 'sync' the two NSMutableArrays with the new results:

```
In: RESULTLISTCONTROLLER.M

- (void) syncWithCart
{
    ShoppingCart *sc = [ShoppingCart sharedCart];
    [sc checkForDuplicates];
    NSMutableSet *listSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:resultList];
    NSUInteger i = 0;

    while (i < [sc.ShoppingCartArray count]) {
        id ShopObject = [sc.ShoppingCartArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([listSet containsObject:ShopObject])
        {
            MyCust *listCust = [listSet member:ShopObject];
            MyCust *shopCust = ShopObject;
            listCust.AmountInShoppingCart = shopCust.AmountInShoppingCart;
            [listSet removeObject:ShopObject];
        } else {i++;}}}
```

This all works pretty well until...

**The 2nd webservice!**

Now here comes the good part: There's a 2nd JSON-WebService the app uses to retrieve external supplier stock. It sometimes contains the same `MyCust` objects, but contains extra information that has to be parsed into the existing objects.

I basically get the first WebService's result into the `getMyCustArray` and the other in the `getExternalCustArray`. I then check if `getMyCustArray` contains an object in the `getExternalCustArray` and update the additional information on the objects and delete the similar object in `getExternalCustArray`. Any leftover objects only available from the supplier will be added using:

```
mergedCustArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[getMyCustArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:getExternalCustArray]];
```

Now the problem is, that when the user checks the same sizes twice, the App doesn't seem to consider the new results as the same.

When I do an NSLog of the ShoppingCartArray, the following shows: 
(original item names obfuscated)

**First Search:**

```
MyCust: SideShowBobsEarWarmers
 Hash: **2082010619**
 AmountInShoppingCart: 4
 **<MyCust: 0x81cee50>**",
    "
 MyCust: SolidSnakesCardBoardBox
 Hash: **4174540990**
 AmountInShoppingCart: 4
 **<MyCust: 0x8190d10>**"
```

**Second Search:** 
the ResultList doesn't retain the MyCust's AmountInShoppingCart values, so I add them to the ShoppingCart again from the ResultList.

```
 MyCust: SideShowBobsEarWarmers
 Hash: **2082010619**
 AmountInShoppingCart: 4
 **<MyCust: 0x81cee50>**",

 MyCust: SolidSnakesCardBoardBox
 Hash: **4174540990**
 AmountInShoppingCart: 4
 **<MyCust: 0x8190d10>**" 
    "
// Different Pointers, although they should be considered Equal.

 MyCust: SideShowBobsEarWarmers
 Hash: **2082010619**
 AantalInWinkelWagen: 3
 **<MyCust: 0x74bc570>**",      
    "
 MyCust: SolidSnakesCardBoardBox
 Hash: **4174540990**
 AantalInWinkelWagen: 2
 **<MyCust: 0x74bc7b0>**"
```

So somehow the compiler allocates those objects in a different memory address/pointer, and then breaks the `isEqual:` function, as far as I can tell.

My guts tell me there's something to do with `NSCopy(able)`, but I'm not quite sure how I'd implement that. If anyone got some good tips for a Shopping Cart system, that's always welcome too. I've got half a mind converting all this to Core Data but would like to have the core functionality in place before doing that.

Comment: I changed the `isEqual` method to:




`-(BOOL) isEqual: (id) rhs
    {
    //Overriding isEqual to make sure MyCust returned from the      webservice are equal to the ones already in the shoppingcart or list
    BOOL ret = NO;
    if ([rhs isKindOfClass: [MyCust class]]) // do not use [self class]
    {
        ret = [self externalItemId] == [rhs externalItemId];
    }
    return ret;
}

-(NSUInteger) hash
{
        return [[self externalItemId] hash];
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In isEqual: method, the line "if (externalItemId != [otherCust externalItemId]) return NO;" is wrong.
I think it should be if (![externalItemId:isEqual:[otherCust externalItemId]]) return NO;

Comment: Wow thanks! That solved it straight away, been driving me mad for a couple of days now.